# Create New Project from my Java's Templates

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-11

I have duplicated and edited the templates "new java class" and "new java main class" in Apache Netbeans 11. My purpose is to have the option to create a new project with my templates. Currently Netbeans creates the project with its own default classes.

I tried right-click -> properties etc, I was unable to reach what I want.

Comment: wich sistem construction is written your template?

Comment: My templates are almost  copies from originals with subtle changes such as curly braces, removed comments, author's position, that sort of thing.